# Azerbaijani to ASCII Transliteration

Tags: php, iconv, transliteration

Is there anything in PHP that will convert the Latin form of Azerbaijani to ASCII, i.e. removing characters unique to the country.

e.g.

```
Məmmədhəsənov => Mammadhasanov
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just the one character that is not handled by the [`Transliterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) class:

Solution:

```
$str = 'Məmmədhəsənov';
$str = preg_replace( '~ə$~', 'eh', $str );
$str = str_replace( array( 'Ə', 'ə' ), array( 'A', 'a' ), $str );
$t = Transliterator::create("Latin-ASCII; NFKD; [^\u0000-\u007A] Remove; NFC");
echo $t->transliterate($str);
```